# Every even number $2n$ can be written in the form $2n= (x+y)^2 + 3x +y $ with $ x,y$ non negative integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone give a hint for the solution of this question?

Question: Every even number $2n$ can be written in the form $2n= (x+y)^2 + 3x +y $ with $ x,y$ non negative integers.

My attempt : I have tried expanding the right hand side and it's obvious that it is even. But how do I proceed to prove that for each and every even integer there exists a value of $ x$ and $y$?  I even tried considering the expression as a quadratic in one of its variables but I still find it a bit difficult to resolve the discriminant as a perfect square. Can someone help here please?

Comment: $2n=(x+y)^2+3x+y\implies(2 (x + y) + 3)^2 = 9 + 8 (n + y)$

Answer (score 3):

By induction you have that $2=(0+1)^2+3\cdot 0+1$. Suppose now that you can write $2n=(x+y)^2+3x+y$, then $2(n+1)=2n+2=(x+y)^2+3x+y+2=((x+1)+(y-1))^2+3(x+1)+(y-1)$,so the thesis is veryfied also for $n+1$ if $y\ge 1$. But suppose $y=0$ then $2n=x^2+3x$ and $2(n+1)=x^2+3x+2=(x+1)^2+(x+1)=(0+(x+1))^2+3\cdot 0+(x+1)$ and so your thesis is true by induction.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $x+y$ by $z$. You want $2n=z(z+1)+2x$, $z\ge x\ge 0$. So $$n=(z+1)z/2+x=1+2+...z +x.$$ Take $z$ maximal  so that $a=1+2+...z\le n$ and $x=n-a$. We only need to check that $z\ge x$. Indeed $a+z+1\ge n+1$. So $x=n-a\le z$.

Answer (score 0):

For a given $n\ge0$, take

$$m:=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\right\rfloor,\\x=n-\frac{m(m+1)}2,\\y=m-x,$$ which are always defined.

E.g. $n=43\to m=8,x=7,y=1; n=3\to m=2,x=0,y=2; n=1000\to m=44, x= 10, y=34\ \cdots$